# Sonarrule to control maximum number of functions inside a class

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint

1. Is there any sonar rule to control the maximum number of functions inside a Java or .Net class?
2. I saw rule

> Files should not have too many lines of code : squid:S00104

It has the default value 750. Can anybody please tell me how to change the default value?

Comment: In SonarQube you can see all the rules, so you can investigate this.

Comment: I already searched, I got squid:S00104 which partially solved my problem. Even in that rule, I do not know how to override default value. Also could not get any rule how to control number of functions. Not sure why this is down voted :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad 1. You are looking for S1448 and S1820. Check:

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1448

https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1820

Ad 2. You can change default value with sql update on database. Check this sql select:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [dbo].[rules_parameters]
WHERE rule_id = 
(SELECT TOP 1 [id] FROM [dbo].[rules] WHERE [plugin_rule_key] = 'S00104')
```